# How can I report all third party licenses in a react native expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently on an internship with a company and they want to publish a mobile app that was built with react native and expo. What are my obligations regarding reporting open source third party libraries and dependencies? What are the specific license requirements?

When I run 'npm ls --depth=0 --platform=android' I get the following list of libraries: [short list of libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lif8J.png)

But if I run 'npm ls --all', I get an extremely long tree of dependcies with their depencies. It's too long to paste in here, but this is a snippet of what it looks like: [long list of libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B48kE.png)

What are the license requirements and which ones do I have to report? Can I just report the short list or do I have to report every single library?

I ran 'npm ls', but I'm not sure if that's all the libraries that the app is using; I'm aware that expo also downloads java dependencies when building the android app, so I'm concerned that this doesn't list those. Expo doesn't seem to have any documentation on how to list libraries and dependencies.

Looking into my package-lock.json file, there seems to be over 20,000 libraries. I"m guessing these are the ones that Expo downloads and doesn't necessarily use in the app. [packagelock json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwRDv.png)

Please let me know if this makes sense. All I need is a list of libraries and their versions and licenses so I can list it on the mobile app without getting in trouble. Thanks!

Comment: npx license-checker --summary

Comment: @DanielBeck license-checker --summary gives this output:

├─ MIT: 1274
├─ ISC: 108
├─ BSD-3-Clause: 31
├─ BSD-2-Clause: 28
├─ Apache-2.0: 20
├─ MIT*: 12
├─ (MIT OR CC0-1.0): 5
├─ Unlicense: 4
├─ WTFPL: 3
├─ BSD*: 3
├─ UNKNOWN: 2
├─ CC0-1.0: 2
├─ 0BSD: 2
├─ Python-2.0: 1
├─ (MIT OR Apache-2.0): 1
├─ Public Domain: 1
├─ CC-BY-4.0: 1
├─ Custom: https://travis-ci.org/component/emitter.png: 1
├─ UNLICENSED: 1
├─ (BSD-3-Clause OR GPL-2.0): 1
├─ (MIT AND Zlib): 1

Do I have to write down the names of all those libraries?

Comment: sorry, I was moving too quickly and didn't post the whole comment :)   That'll give you a list of the licenses your dependencies are using; using that you can learn what the specific requirements are per license.